# autocomplete select event in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have an autocomplete on datagridview from an sql datbase.

I want that if an item selected from the autocomplete list in one cell the other cells will complete automatilcly from the database. I can't find an autocomplete event that indicates an item was selected.

Comment: There is no such thing as auto-complete on a `DataGridView`. You're using you're own terminology that is too vague. You need to explain exactly what you're doing using specific terminology that everyone is familiar with. Do you mean that you have a text box column in your grid and you have set the `AutoCompleteMode` to something other than `None` on the editing control? If so, that's what you need to say, so that we know exactly what we're dealing with.

Comment: That said, none of that is probably relevant at all. When you're editing a cell in a `DataGridView`, an editing control is created and embedded and that's where the changes happen. The grid doesn't know anything about those changes until you end the editing session and the final value is pushed back to the cell. At that point, the `CellValueChanged` event is raised and that is probably what you should be handling. If you want to react to changes in the editing control then you need to handle an event of the editing control. You could then force the cell `Value` to update.

Comment: I'd do this as a parent child relationship; set the parent id and have a data bound datarelation provide the related values. It wouldn't be on the one row though. If you wanted it thus you could probably achieve similar with a bunch of DataColumn whose expression are set to Parent.Whatever, or a datagridviewcombobox whose ValueMember is the related parent id , the DisplayMember is a different parent column and whose DataPropertyName is the id column in the child table

Comment: yes, I use the autocomplete in a textbox in the DataGridView. I don't to use CellValueChanged because I want to connect to my DB only when an item select from the autocomplete